# Display content for specific user

Tags: magento2.3, session, full-page-cache

I'm trying to display content for admins only on the frontend (product view), however, with FPC enabled, once an admin opens that product, all the other users will see that same content.
I have the method below on my Helper, which returns true/false to the .phtml file in question.

```
public function isAdmin(){
        $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getId();

        if($customerId == 3){
            return true;
        } else return false;

        return false;
    }
```

I know I can't get customer session when the FPC is enabled and I'm looking for a solution. What should be my approach?
Should I create a custom http variable, if so, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Consider loading the admin-specific content by an AJAX request that bypasses the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be just to make an Ajax request on the frontend to pull the data from a custom controller.

But the Magento implementation of it is known as **Private Content**. Private content have a few benefits over just a plain Ajax request, since it implements caching/data invalidation etc. I've attached some links to the devdocs / blog posts on Private Content.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html

https://www.siphor.com/add-private-content-in-magento-2/

https://www.hellomagento2.com/private-content/

Comment: Thanks, great help, I've been able to get the data I need. However, how do I treat it now? I want to use that customsection().msg as a conditional, for example, if(customsection().msg == true) { //displayinfo }

Comment: I've found the answer: <div id="checkAdmin" data-bind="if: customsection().msg">